# Registering new accounts MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

I have an online gta san andreas server and have recently changed the game mode, but when a user tries to create a new account to play with these errors appear below:

> Blockquote
>   [13:41:34] [ERROR] ID: 1364 - Error: Field 'Sexo' doesn't have a default value - Callback - OnQueryFinish - Query: INSERT INTO `usuarios` (username, password,posX,posY,posZ,vida,money,banco,skin,Registro,Email,EMS,Edad) VALUES ('Onion_Games','91752300','1715.5295','-1900.1307','13.5664','100','6000','10000','250','22/09/2019','oniongames@gmail.com',1,23)

how can i fix this?

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE usuarios` and edit the question and add the details of this query. Most likely, your `Sexo` column in the table is an enum with no default value defined, and your `INSERT` query is not explicitly entering it as well; that is why the error.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that:

- when inserting, you did not provide a value for field `Sexo`
- this column was defined as `NOT NULL` when the table was created, and no default value was defined

Possible solutions are:

- provide the value when inserting
- set up a default value in the definition of the table